# Arrays in Zsh. Check if any of the following variables is not defined

Tags: shell, zsh, environment-variables

Say we have a set of variables that we want to test if they are defined, and set a condition if any of them are not.

I am thinking of proceeding with something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
d=("$VAR1" "$VAR2" "$VAR3")    
for x in $d;
do
    if <variable_x_not_defined>
       UNDEFINED_VARIABLES="True"
    fi
done
```

I tested with different options for `<variable_x_not_defined>` condition without luck. Am I using the array properly here? How can I do this in Zsh?

Comment: What if `VAR1=''`… This doesn't look like a proper use of arrays…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice that `for x in $d` skips empty strings:

```
VAR1=a
VAR2=
VAR3=c
d=("$VAR1" "$VAR2" "$VAR3")
for x in $d; do
    echo $x
done

a
c
```

(note the missing empty line between `a` and `c`)

Using the bash- and ksh-compatible array expansion, `"${d[@]}"` seems to do the trick:

```
VAR1=a
VAR2=
VAR3=c
d=("$VAR1" "$VAR2" "$VAR3")
for x in "${d[@]}"; do
    echo $x
done

a

c
```

So your script could do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
d=("$VAR1" "$VAR2" "$VAR3")
undefined_variables=false
for x in "${d[@]}"; do
    if [[ -z "${x}" ]]; then
        undefined_variables=true
        break
    fi
done
if $undefined_variables; then
    echo "Found some undefined variables"
fi
```

Also note that the `for x in $d` form assumes that the `KSH_ARRAYS` option is not set, which might not always be true.

---

Alternatively, you could set the array to the *names* of the variables rather than the values, and then use a "nameref" inside the loop.  That way the quoting is simpler, and you can see which variables were unset.

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
VAR1=a
VAR2=b
VAR3=
vars=(VAR1 VAR2 VAR3)
undefined_variables=false
for var in $vars; do        # or 'for var in "${vars[@]}"' if KSH_ARRAYS might be on
    if [[ -z "${(P)var}" ]]; then
        echo "$var is empty"
        undefined_variables=true
    fi
    # alternatively to test for defined variable as opposed to empty:
    if ((! ${(P)+var})); then
        echo "$var is not set"
        undefined_variables=true
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 7):

To check whether an array contains at least one empty element, you can do:

```
if ((i = array[(I)])); then
  echo "array contains at least one empty element (${i}th)"
else
  echo "array doesn't contain empty elements"
fi
```

The `(I)` subscript flag in `$array[(I)pattern]` returns the indice of the last element that matches the `pattern` or `0` if not found.

Or you can count the number of empty elements with:

```
if ((n = ${(M)#array[@]:#})); then
  echo "array contains $n empty elements"
else
  echo "array doesn't contain any empty element"
fi
```

`${(M)array[@]:#pattern}` expands to the elements that match `pattern`. Adding `#` gives the count.